# Is there a technical reason why most touch screens use glass rather than plastic?

Tags: touchscreen, materials, flexible, durability, plastic

Most modern touch screens in portable devices are made of glass.

This glass often breaks if accidentally dropped. Also, it is very reflective, making it difficult to use in strong light.

I know that touch screens without glass exist. For example, the multi-touch screen on my e-ink [e-reader](https://web.archive.org/web/20160512044950/http://www.onyx-international.com/index.php/en/boox-products/boox-i-series) has a plastic front. I remember many other examples, such as the personal in-flight entertainment systems on many airplanes.

What are the reasons that most modern portable touch devices come with a glass panel on their fronts, rather than plastic or something else?

The cracking of glass seems to be a pretty big problem.

**Edit:** I've seen a lot of cracked touch devices, and it's nearly always only the front panel that's cracked. The actual display is usually fine underneath. Even the digitizer usually works perfectly.

Comment: 1. Revenue from planned obsolescence, 2, see 1.

Comment: @Passerby LOL. Thanks. If you are serious, you can post that as an answer, expanding on it.

Comment: If I could source or get a company to admit they purposely design their products to break in months, let alone years, I would. I'd also be heading a class action lawsuit, but that's another story.

Comment: @Passerby LOL... Just make a phone call to Apple or Samsung, I'm sure they'll admit it in writing...

Comment: Re, your edit. The Glass/Digitizer is typically a few micrometers above the display, courtesy of the glue strips used to join the two. That accounts for why the display is saved. That distance is enough to blunt the damage.

Comment: @Passerby I see, thanks. On devices that feature a plastic front, rather than glass, is the glass in the inner glass of the LCD more likely to break in the case of a drop? (Compared to the glass front device.)

Comment: In terms of user experience, glass screens also feel nicer and are less yielding.

Comment: @JAB Some people actually think plastic feels better, though. So it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I would imagine the use of plastic screens on in-flight entertainment systems was influenced by weight concerns. Saving 100g per seat is a win.

Comment: @TMN Good point! Saving 100g per iPad would also be a win though, but probably not a big enough one. Also, the in flight screens are in little or no danger of getting scratched, as they t won't be lying around in backpacks, etc.

Comment: @Passerby Someone did pretty much make that an answer. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/233193/108245

Comment: There are different touchscreen technologies. Most likely this is referring to capacitive touch? Resistive touch requires a flexible panel (as far as I know).

Comment: Modern glass is tough - really tough.  It can take durable antireflection and anti-smudge coatings and it is extremely resistant to scratching.  There is no suitable plastic that could work as well.  http://www.corninggorillaglass.com/

Comment: My Lumia820 broke the inner AMOLED display and the inside layer of glass (with polarizer), but the front glass (with touch) remained intact and I'm still using it after replacing the display.

Comment: @Agent_L Interesting!  How did the drop or damage happen?

Comment: @Fiksdal It felt perfectly flat screen down on a wooden floor. This is an old and thick model with front glass not bonded to the display. I guess the g-force broke the inner screen and then the broken screen hit the front glass from the inside as it lost rigidity. Because cracks on the display and the screen were pretty good matching.

Comment: @Agent_L But I thought only one component, the display, was cracked? What was the second component with matching cracks?

Comment: @Fiksdal The front glass have 2 layers: outside with digitizer and inside with polarizer (not counting the display). The digitizer is intact but polarizer is broken in exactly same way as the screen. Cracks can be seen with correct angle and can be felt with fingernail (after disassembling the phone ofc). This is how I found out the glass have 2 layers.

Comment: @Agent_L I see. Interesting.

Comment: Also I am not sure if a drop of hot coco would create a melting spot in my display? Though many plastics can withstand heat but may be they will increase the cost.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When decisions about consumer electronics are made, many reasons beyond technical come into play. There is no valid reason for a phone to be disassembled in 7 pieces in order to replace a battery, yet that's how one of the most popular phones is made. Mobile phones are as much a product of marketing as they are of electronics, and many design decisions become clear when you take a look at that perspective.

Glass looks good, so it sell good. And when it shatters, people have to pay again - either for a new phone, or for a glass replacement job.

Plastic doesn't shatter or otherwise fall apart, unless you try to cut or burn it on purpose. It can also be made matte, which makes the screen much more readable in presence of reflections and glares. Since plastic doesn't have to be hard, it can be made thinner than glass, improving touch sensitivity.

Unfortunately, it looks cheap even before it is scratched (and plain terrible after), so you can't make big money selling phones with plastic screens. Worse, people will carry these cheap-looking phones for ages (because the screen won't shatter), projecting that cheap-looking and outdated image of your brand everywhere they go. So you either go out of business, or switch to glass like everyone else.

Comment: Ah, my old Game Boy Color comes to mind :)

Comment: @Fiksdal I don't think your GBC has a touchscreen (though it does have a plastic screen finish).

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about the not-so-pretty plastic screen and it getting worse over time.

Comment: FYI, it can be polished with the same product they use on scratched CDs, if you feel nostalgic enough.

Comment: Cool :) Unfortunately it's no longer with me. But that polish would probably be useful for plastic screen phones too?

Comment: "There is no valid reason for a phone to be disassembled in 7 pieces in order to replace a battery" -- untrue; all other things being equal, a non removable battery as in the iPhone allows for more battery volume (and therefore charge time) for a given overall package volume. Whether that's *more* or *less* valuable than the ability to swap the battery is a reasonable thing to debate, but it's a valid design decision.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I'm not arguing against the battery **design**, but about its **location**. A non-removable battery could still be located under a removable cover, not under several layers of LCD, PCB and flex cables. Take almost any Android tablet: they have non-removable batteries too (and often even require you to solder the new battery), but there's much less stuff to take apart, usually only the back cover.

Comment: It would still incur a volume penalty. Plastic has thickness. Connectors have volume. Engineering has tradeoffs.

Comment: Regarding the battery being under the LCD, etc., is this something new? I remember one time I had to change the battery in an iPhone 4(S?). All I had to do was remove two screws, take off the back cover, remove a third screw inside, and change the battery, then put everything back on. Of course, that's still way more work than changing the battery on my Samsung S3, which can be done by hand. But is it even more complicated in newer iPhones?

Comment: I don't think the argument that it is marketing rather than technical constraints is very strong.  There are lots of technical reasons for using glass screens given in other answers, and even yours (scratches).

Comment: Plastic scratch resistance is abysmal compared to glass. And what's the intended use of a touch screen? - yep, scratching it with the dust under your fingertips. Sorry, I had to downvote because you're simply wrong. Russell is also right and arguing with his fine points only shows your answer is based on faith, not facts.

Comment: @Agent_L *Plastic scratch resistance is abysmal compared to glass* - isn't that what I say in my answer as well? Or do you disagree with the word "terrible"?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev No, you wrote "Plastic is virtually indestructible". Then it's "**If** it's scratched" - but that's a very big "if" considering the paragraph before states it can't be damaged at all.

Comment: @Agent_L Well, a scratched screen remains readable and otherwise functional, contrary to a shattered screen. I rephrased that part of the answer.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev So is glass. I myself have a functional phone with cracked glass and if you look up classifieds you can find numerous examples of phones "touch cracked but working". And this is still unfair comparison - carrying in the pocket is the intended purpose while dropping is not. Scratch resistance is the #1 requirement here and plastic simply sucks for this. Planned obsolescence is everywhere but in the glass.

Comment: @Agent_L Well, if you can read on a shattered screen, good for you. I can't.

Comment: There is a major valid reason for making the battery hard to replace: it destroys the profit margins for stores removing the factory battery from every device, replacing it with a used, virtually-dead one, and selling the removed battery as a replacement. This is widespread practice in certain markets.

Comment: This has probably more to do with the fact that most plastic touchscreens are cheap or don't care too much about usability, but I have yet to see any plastic touchscreen that had acceptable performance. I mean those industry handhelds, airplane screens, old navigation devices - all plastic touchscreens, all horrible beyond recognition. Recognize prints slowly, low accuracy, you can press *into* the screen, no multi-touch support,.. Most of those are presumably resistive and not capacitive though.

Comment: @Voo Slow input recognition is almost certainly due to a slow CPU processing touchscreen input. Delay in touchscreen electronics in unnoticeable.

Comment: `people have to pay again - either for a new phone, or for a glass replacement job.`- well, that's a horrible strategy because most people will buy a phone from a different company, because they have first-hand experience of poor build quality from the company whose phone they just had break on them. And over time, people will eventually flock to buy phones from the one company whose screens do **not** break easily.

Answer (score 69):

### Title of question: Is there a technical reason why most touch screens use glass rather than plastic?

Note the word "technical" and not "marketing"

> What are the reasons that most modern portable touch devices come with
>   a glass panel on their fronts, rather than plastic or something else?

Glass (as a cheap and common material) has a good dielectric constant (more than most cheap plastics) and this makes the change in capacitance bigger for those devices using that technology. This makes life easier on the electronics that has to detect finger positions and movement.

[image]

Taken from [this](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjC9ISixczMAhWqDMAKHZ6GD1wQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.farnell.com%2Fdatasheets%2F1504633.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHwpwiZyTQJVshxFOs6semj3hMIiA&sig2=toca6tC7t8xfCD82nABieg&bvm=bv.121421273,d.ZGg&cad=rja) article

Comment: Note that some cheaper/older devices do not use a capacitive touch screen but a *resistive* touchscreen. Usually these work best with a stylus or a fingernail. Capacitive touchscreens do not require any pressure to register a touch, resistive touchscreens do need some force (to make a connection between two resistive layers).

Comment: Correct but as for making plastic as sensitive as glass that is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info! Would it be on topic here to ask that as a sepreate question?

Comment: Is it an EE question or a physics question?

Comment: I would phrase the question:  "Is it possible to make a plastic touch screen as sensitive and accurate as a glass touch screen?" This sounds like an EE question? (Although of course, all engineering involves physics.)

Comment: Ask it then but it's not something I can answer.

Comment: OK :) Maybe someone else can :)

Comment: @FakeMoustache I see.  As you said, I think resistive is quite rare these days?

Comment: Yes resistive touchscreens are getting rare these days because of their bad performance, they're not made of glass so scratch easily and look worse, capacitive touch screens have become cheaper making the resistive variant mostly obsolete.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Then there is infrared, which I have on my plastic eReader.

Comment: @Andyaka I think you're reading a bit too much on the dielectric constant. If you look at chapter 2.3.3 in the same document they go on to say that 10mm plastic cover"glass" is quite usable. So for your average <1mm thick mobile device "glass" this is bit of a non-issue. On the other hand if you want teenager-resistant display you want to go with thick materials..

Comment: @FakeMoustache Resistive is going strong on medical sector and anywhere else where you may get the display wet. While you can in fact reject water droplets on display, this is hardly foolproof and requires combining self and mutual capacitance technologies in one display for best effect. Infrared is no good and it's mostly used for large size displays these days. There are various other technologies such as optical (they're watching you!) and various surface wave technologies but PCAP + resistive are dominating by vast margin.

Comment: @Barleyman - I genuinely look forward to seeing your answer.

Comment: @Andyaka You're not wrong with the dielectric constant, but it's not really an issue in most cases. But glass is generally the better display cover material. Plastic windows are not very popular. I commented on this here as well: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/233141/is-it-possible-to-make-a-plastic-touch-screen-as-sensitive-and-accurate-as-a-gla/233171#233171

Comment: @fiksdal After reviewing some technical material, it turns out the actual touch sensor sometimes uses plastic but glass is more popular and actually cheaper these days. Plastic can be made thinner on the other hand.

Comment: @fiksdal Geoff Walker has more information on touch technology than anyone else and it's all available free of charge right here: http://www.walkermobile.com/PublishedMaterial.htm

Comment: @Barleyman: Resistive in medical sector is just backwardsness/resistance to change. The UX for resistive touch screens is utterly awful.

Comment: @R.. Possibly they're resistive to change because having a drug dispenser et al go haywire because the display got some body fluid on it is a non-issue.

Comment: @Barleyman: If that's an issue, the possibility of a visitor or other non-qualified person accidentally doing something dangerous via the UI is also an issue, and there should be proper access controls to ensure that it doesn't happen... But of course the medical sector is utterly backwards on security and access control, too...

Comment: Andy, I want to comment on this vs. the answer of @DmitryGrigoryev . My opinion, as well as which answer I accept, is largely irrelevant, as I have near zero knowledge on EE. Anyway, I think the two answers highlight two different things, and both seem important. I believe Dmitry's answer is also technical. I believe you probably agree that vulnerability to scratches and aesthetics are *part* of the reason why plastic is not widely used. Similarly, Dmitry probably agrees with your points regarding the sensitivity and accuracy of glass. It seems to me that both answers are very valid,

Comment: @Andyaka I also found this very relevant: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/233171/108245

Comment: @Fiksdal this is an EE site and I have provided technical answers based purely on electronic or electrical standpoints. How you choose to select the best answer is down to you but don't expect everyone to agree!!

Comment: @Andyaka No, of course not, it would be insane to expect everyone to agree. I just wanted to say that I believe both answers seem very valid to me. Actually, an ideal answer might even include both aspects. But as I said, I have nearly zero knowledge on EE.

Comment: @Fiksdal having virtually zero knowledge on EE puts you in a very unique position for judging the best answer LOL.

Comment: @Andyaka lol,  yeah it's funny, because I can choose which answer is on the top,  and that answer often gets more votes simply because it's what people see first.  And this question has been featured in the "hot"  category all over SE,  so a lot of non EE users have probably seen and voted on it. If one answer gets a lot more upvotes than the accepted answer,  then it should probably rise to the top regardless. But that has probably been discussed in meta.

Answer (score 36):

You mention cracking as a downside to using glass, but most touchscreens will encounter far more potential scratch-causing events than crack-causing events.

Glass is highly scratch-resistant: at a [Mohs hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohs_scale_of_mineral_hardness) of 5.5, it's harder than anything else in your pocket (steel is around 4).  Synthetic sapphire is even more scratch-resistant: at a hardness of 9, the only common material that can scratch it is diamond.  In contrast, most plastics have a hardness less than 1, and will get scratched up in short order (among other hazards, fingernails have a hardness between 2 and 3).

Comment: BTW [this site](http://www.oakton.edu/user/4/billtong/eas100lab/hardness.htm) says that steel can scratch minerals of up to 6.5 hardness, and my phone screen has several tiny scratches by now, so it's definitely NOT harder than anything in my pocket

Comment: According to the Walter Isaacson biography of Steve Jobs the original iPhone prototype had a plastic screen but go so scratched up in Jobs' pocket by his keys that Jobs insisted on the iPhone having a glass screen

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, steel comes in a wide range of hardness grades.  Mild and stainless steels tend towards the lower end of that range, while a hardness of 6.5 is for a steel file (ie. tool steel specifically engineered for maximized scratch hardness).

Comment: You should add Gorilla Glass and other such highly-engineered materials to that answer. As far as I'm aware, no smartphone yet uses synthetic sapphire for the screen — phones are still too big for that to be economical — but there are materials commonly used in high-end smartphones that *approach* the hardness of sapphire, splitting the difference between your Mohs numbers.

Comment: I sent a Wacom bamboo touch/tablet back as not fit for purpose as it scratched the first time I touched it. I didn't have it long enough to drop it.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Sapphire is too expensive for screens, but most cost-effective for the objective lenses on many phone cameras.

Answer (score 18):

Glass is hard, and therefore brittle, so it shatters.

Plastic (acrylic or polycarbonate) is softer, so more prone to scratches. It's certainly a possibility and some cheap phones have plastic touchscreens.

But the underlying LCD behind the transparent touchscreen has to be made of glass, due to high temperature parts of the process. So that's still vulnerable to breaking.

The ultimate is synthetic sapphire, which Apple were going to use but abandoned for some reason. Much harder and harder to shatter than glass.

Comment: Thanks! Are all LCD's made of glass? What about Amoled, etc? Also, I've seen hundreds of shattered touch devices, and it's nearly always the front panel that's shattered. The actual display is usually fine underneath. Even the digitizer usually works perfectly.

Comment: I have not seen any LCDs that are **not** made using glass. That does not mean these do not exist of course. But it would surprise me if they did. LCDs need electrically conductive patterns on the glass. Maybe these patterns cannot be made so easily on something which is not glass. I do not expect that an Amoled display needs glass as it consists of LEDs on a substrate.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Thanks! BTW, I just read on Wikipedia that glass-free Amoled is in the works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39493/discussion-between-fiksdal-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: FYI, Apple did wind up using the synthetic sapphire, but only for the Home button (or whatever that button is called on an iPhone) and maybe also the rear camera. I watched a YouTube video about it a few weeks ago, a guy took steel wool and sandpaper to the screen and the button to show the difference in how much it scratched.

Comment: @pjc50 What makes you think sapphire will be harder to shatter, though? Doesn't hardness come with brittleness?

Comment: @DanHenderson I think they also used the sapphire on the Apple Watch?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I've also heard that sapphire shatters easily.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I have shattered sapphire (actually cleaving wafers), and it is no more difficult to do than for glass. In fact it may be easier, because making "toughened sapphire" is impossible, and unlike glass, sapphire is a crystalline material so cracks propagate readily along the lattice plane directions. Its only advantage in this application seems to be its hardness. A sputtered coating of (amorphous) alumina on top of ordinary glass would seem to be a better choice for toughness. Polycrystalline diamond is very tough but mass production is constrained by economics.

Comment: Relevant story to your answer: http://www.businessinsider.com/steve-jobs-new-iphone-screen-2012-1

Comment: @FakeMoustache - what do you mean by that? Look around the office and you'll see plastic LCDs literally everywhere. You're probably using one right now.

Comment: @Jasmine You should look again, those displays are themselves are made using glass. Maybe there's a plastic window on top of it but the LCD itself will have glass plates. Smash one with a hammer and you'll see I'm right.

Answer (score 5):

**Here's some history:**

Back in the day, almost all of the early touch (not-so-smart) phones used plastic displays. It was, in fact, *Steve Jobs*, who demanded that the first iPhones use unscratchable glass.

He said that consumers would carry their smartphones with keys in their pockets and products which were easily damaged weren't acceptable from a corporation like Apple.

This was less than 3 months before the iphone's launch date. 
“I want a glass screen," Steve is quoted as saying. "And I want it perfect in six weeks.”

Obviously, other companies followed suit.

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/steve-jobs-new-iphone-screen-2012-1?IR=T

Answer (score 3):

Resistive touch screens are plastic

Capacitive are glass - for capacitive touchscreen to work, there is wires manufactured on the glass itself - this up to just recently was possible on glass only so this is why it is glass.

Also LCDs are from glass for the same reason, there are already plastic film LCDs but are pretty new (like flexible amoleds and flexible epaper)

Most ereaders uses IR touch sensing(which enables to use plastic covering of the display, but the epaper module itself is glass based again)

Comment: This is false: plastic PCAP displays existed for a long time. I own one of the first android smartphones and it has plastic finish.

Comment: [Dell P2418HT](https://www.dellemc.com/resources/en-us/asset/data-sheets/products/electronics-accessories/dell_24_touch_monitor_p2418ht_product_data_sheet.pdf) uses a projected _capacitive_ system and it's made from plastic (the brochure says "Eliminate the need for glass screen found in traditional monitors with an anti-glare surfaces which reduces distracting reflections and fingerprints").